# Angular4 router conflicted URL with parameter

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I have 3 routes, one for the app module, an other for the admin section and a last one for the client side. Here they are :

```js
-- App routing --
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

-- Admin routing --
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AdminComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'evenements', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'evenements', component: AdminEventComponent }
        ]
    }
  ];
  
-- Client routing --
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: CoreComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: ':city', component: HomeComponent }
        ]
    }
  ];
```

The problem is that when I try to go to `http://myDomain/admin`, the router try to resolve /admin as :city which is a parameter in the core routing.

How to tell angular's router to resolve `http://myDomain/admin` as /admin and if other value then resolve it as :city ?

Thank you

**Update:** 
I solved this issue by changing the order of declared modules in my app-module, I had to import the AppRoutingModule before the ClientModule... It seems weird but it works.

**Update2:**
This issue was not solved by the update1, router ignored the client router module when inverting the order of imports

Comment: why are you using a path param type route `:city`

Comment: Because I need it to show to user informations about a city

Comment: It's a dynamic param, I need to have in my URL `http://myDomain/City1` or `http://myDomain/City2` and give the informations for the right one

Comment: sorry my bad i mistook it

Comment: i would suggest you to remove the component from both the admin and client route just the top level and just use path . as you are using lazy loading

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's not the right way to go

Comment: I am not sure if the structure you post here is the actual way you are structuring your routers, but they all have the same name, thus the last one is overriding the previous ones. How do you specify each of the routes for different router-outlets or modules?

Comment: Because every route is in a separeted module, I'm using forRoot in the app routing module and forChild in the others

Comment: I just saw your update now. Have you tried to remove `pathMatch: 'full'` after using update 1?

Comment: Yes I tried with and without pathMatch but nothing to do . . .

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the issue is to change the path `:city` to `home/:city`, but that may not be what you want to do.

**EDIT:** Removed old answer that did not work, keeping only the above answer as an alternative method to solve the issue described by the OP.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but the first solution doesn't feet my needs as I don't want to have `http://domain/home/:city` and the second one is not working.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. Did you try to add `pathMatch:'full'` on all paths in all routes?

Comment: Yes and it made a mess :( , I'm trying to understand why the router doesn't check for /admin first before trying to resolve it as :city. It's given me a headache

Comment: Order has a lot to say when it comes to these routes. If your `admin` is before your `:city`, I understand it is giving you problems. Make sure that your `admin` path is being evaluated before `:city` if you have not already.

Comment: It works well if I import the adminModule before the clientModule. However, adminModule had to be lazy loaded, that means that I must not import it in the app module.

Comment: I guess you were able to find your answer then. I am happy to hear that. Good work figuring it out.

Comment: No I don't . . . I know that it could work if I import the admin module, but it doesn't feet my need, because I want the admin module to be lazy loaded, so I can't import it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154803/discussion-between-john-and-zak).